$f_n \xrightarrow{d} f$ if and only if $f_n \xrightarrow{m} f$ in $(L^0([0,1]), d)$ where $d(f,g) = \int_0^1 \frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{1 + |f(x)-g(x)|}dx$

Let $L^0([0,1])$ be the vector space of Lebesgue-measurable functions on $[0,1]$. Let $d$ be the metric on $L^0([0,1])$ given by $$d(f,g) = \int_0^1 \frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{1 + |f(x)-g(x)|}\, dx.$$
Prove that $f_n \xrightarrow{d} f$ (convergence in the metric) if and only if $f_n \xrightarrow{m} f$ (convergence in measure.)

My work. Suppose $f_n \xrightarrow{m} f$ and fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Now,
$$\begin{align*}
d(f_n,f) = \int_0^1 \frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}{1 + |f_n(x)-f(x)|}\, dx = \int_{\{|f_n-f| > \varepsilon\}} \frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}{1 + |f_n(x)-f(x)|}\, dx + \int_{\{|f_n-f| \leq \varepsilon\}}  \frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}{1 + |f_n(x)-f(x)|}\, dx.
\end{align*}$$
We can bound the second integral as
$$\int_{\{|f_n-f| \leq \varepsilon\}}  \frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}{1 + |f_n(x)-f(x)|}\, dx \le \varepsilon \int_{\{|f_n-f| \leq \varepsilon\}}  \frac{1}{1 + |f_n(x)-f(x)|}\, dx \le \varepsilon\int_0^1\, dx = \varepsilon.$$
For the first integral,
$$ \int_{\{|f_n-f| > \varepsilon\}} \frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}{1 + |f_n(x)-f(x)|}\, dx \le \int_{\{|f_n-f| > \varepsilon\}}\, dx = m(\{|f_n-f| > \varepsilon\}).$$
In total,
$$d(f_n,f) \le \varepsilon + m(\{|f_n-f| > \varepsilon\}).$$
So, $$0\le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \, d(f_n,f) \le \varepsilon + \limsup_{n\to\infty} m(\{|f_n-f| > \varepsilon\}) = \varepsilon.$$
Since $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} \, d(f_n,f) = 0$, i.e., $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \,d(f_n,f) = 0$.
For the other direction, suppose $f_n \xrightarrow{d} f$, i.e., $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 \frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}{1 + |f_n(x)-f(x)|}\, dx = 0.$$
I'm not sure where to go next, to show $f_n \xrightarrow{m} f$. Thanks for any help!

$x>\epsilon$ implies $\frac x {1+x}>\frac {\epsilon} {1+\epsilon }$

A related question:  If $d(x,y)$ is a metric, then $\frac{d(x,y)}{1 + d(x,y)}$ is also a metric. See part (b) of the question: $ d$ and $d_b(x,y) = \dfrac{d(x,y)}{1 + d(x,y)}$ are equivalent metrics

Let
$$E_{~n,\epsilon}:=\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq\epsilon\}.$$
Then
$$\frac\epsilon{1+\epsilon}m(E_{~n,\epsilon})\leq\int_{E_{~n,\epsilon}}\frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}{1 + |f_n(x)-f(x)|}dx\leq\int_0^1\frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|}{1 + |f_n(x)-f(x)|}dx=d(f_n,f)\to0.$$
Therefore $f_n \xrightarrow{m} f$.
